# rails 3.1 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Standard new rails app has issue showing the rails.png

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
```

I have tried moving the .png file around to various places in assets and assets/images and also the older place 'public' or 'public/images' and changing the page but nothing has helped.  Please answer if you have seen and resolved this.  I have tried about 20 different combo's myself.

Version:
'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'

Comment: looks like here is `/assets/` dir permissions problem

Comment: sure but I've never seen this in other new apps on this machine for other rails versions.  I am hoping to find someone who has experienced/resolved this.

Comment: Yes it is permissions and chmod 777 images/rails.png resolves this but doesn't really address the issue.  I haven't had to do this before with other rails applications and I am pretty nervous about doing that for this image if it will mean similar issue for other assets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No route matches \[GET\] "/assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It must have been an rc4 issue as the final release didn't have this issue.

*11/27/11 - I now wonder if this was just due to the asset pipeline that was introduced in rails 3.1, requiring the* `rake assets:precompile` *command (compiles and copies images, css and js from* `app/assets` *to* `public/`.
*If anyone finds that to be the case, please add a comment!*

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, guess a few people following the RoR 3.0 tutorial will have the same problem when reaching Section 4.1.2 ;-)

Answer (score 31):

I just had a problem throwing a similar error. In my case I was starting the rails server in production mode in Mac OSX using the standard WEBrick. It threw this error because of the line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

in config/environments/production.rb.

That is set because on most production machines the web server itself will handle this.

It looks like you were having a different problem, but I'll post this here for others that run into this error.

Comment: this did the fix for me - after searching all over the net, this made me realize how to make it work with webrick. I strongly upvote this.

Comment: Glad to help :) Shame to see some joker downvote... I'm sure many people will find this useful.

Comment: it also worked for me. now I'm wondering how could I run locally a production environment without have to change this config, because in my production machine it must be 'false'. any ideas?

Comment: @seixasfelipe yes - create a new environment that's identical to production except for that line