# No route matches [GET] /assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails app that I'm trying to test in the production environment. I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` which generated all of my assets in /public/assets. The problem is that when I start my app w/ `RAILS_ENV=production rails s thin` I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-eff78fd67423795a7be3aa21512f0bd2.css"):
```

This file does exist though at `/public/assets/application-eff78fd67423795a7be3aa21512f0bd2.css`.

Any thoughts as to why I'm getting this `RoutingError`?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

In production mode, Rails will not be responsible for serving static assets. Therefore, you are getting this error. Thin won't do it either, since it's just a wrapper around Rails.

This is controlled by this setting in `config/environments/production.rb` in your application:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
```

Or in Rails 5:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Or set `ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES']` to true.

You can either set to that `true` or use a real server like Apache or Nginx which will serve the static assets. I suspect Pow may also do it.

---

If you're on Heroku, they recommend the use of the `rails_12factor` gem which enables this setting by default. Place the gem into a `production` group in your `Gemfile`, like this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Anyone know if this a solution to the said problem when deploying to heroku?

Comment: Clear answer, many thanks. I got to this page as I was testing production environment using `thin` on my development machine. I was compiling the assets but `application.css` was empty and the server log gave error of the OP.

Comment: In Rails 4 it will be `config.serve_static_files`. `config.serve_static_assets` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.

Comment: Deploying to a RHEL distribution, I haven't touched the default environment configuration, just added the rails_12factor gem in Rails v4.2.4,  now everything is okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Onur: This means that your Rails application will be serving the assets, rather than your webserver. I do not recommend this configuration at all because it can make your Rails server slower.

Comment: Default configuration seems to be checking whether an environment variable is present for this option. In this case this sets it to false for me, but from now on I will pay attention and take your advice into your account. That was a nice tip. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: i am having similar problem cannot download attachment. getting error as  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/vol_dev/imported/32790/freshest_data_2016-02-01_2016-02-24.csv". I am using a server and attachment is stored outside rails application. path from root folder.

Comment: I turned 'serve_static...' on.  It works on most files, but on one image and some of the JS it does not.  Besides the useless rename of the env setting for static_assets, is there some other all-too-clever breakage in the asset system that has been foisted upon us in v4.2 vs v4.0?  Maybe I should just put a route in the routes file for every asset that doesn't work with whatever they did?

Comment: On Heroku, `rails_12factor` gem is not required any more in Rails 6 as the Rails 6 default takes care of it. Reference: <https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#heroku-gems>

Answer (score 12):

Adding to what Ryan said above, the Rails asset pipeline guide describes how to setup Apache or nginx to serve the static assets for you.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

You really should setup nginx or Apache to serve static assets, as they're much better optimized for this task than mongrel/thin/unicorn.

Answer (score 7):

Just solved the same problem. In my case Ryan's answer was not helpful. Bratsche pointed to the Rails Guides, unfortunately this didn't work for me too. However the resource was helpful. So I took Nginx configuration from there and added the **root** directive, pointing to the public directory. Without this it doesn't work.

```
   # serve static assets
   location ~ ^/assets/ {
     expires 1y;
     root  /path/to/my/cool_project/public;
     add_header Cache-Control public;

     add_header ETag "";
     break;
   }
```

Restart nginx, and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

In rails 5, the `config.serve_static_files` option has changed, so now you need to have

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

to serve assets locally.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you didn't need to modify any default configs.
You just ***recompile assets file again***.

## remove public/assets

> 1.rake assets:clobber RAILS_ENV=production

## assets compile

> 2.rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
>
> 3.restart server,eg(nginx)

Comment: @SteveO7,obviously,rails use assets pipleline in dev mode by default.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4.2 has added/changed this line in your config/environments/ staging.rb and production.rb files:

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

If RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES is not set, and you are service assets from your Rails server (like with Unicorn), then it will default to "false", and the RoutingError will occur.

This is an easy fix:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simplest option. Configuration usually depends on server environment and making it configurable with an env-variable is nice.

Answer (score 1):

I use **mina**+**puma**+**nginx** to deploy my Rails 5 application, I got

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-658cf2ab3ac93aa5cb41a762b52cf49d7184509c307922cd3fbb61b237a59c1a.css")
```

check config/environments/production.rb

```
# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

**NGINX already handles this**, config it corretcly

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

things will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

## config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

then run command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

then push all compiles files and manifest file to server.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody get here with the same error in the test environment as I do, here's what helped me:

```
rails assets:clobber assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test
```

then:

```
ps axu | grep your-username
```

to find `spring server` process and his PID then kill it via:

```
kill <spring-server-PID>
```