# datepicker not working on FF and chrome but it works on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, datepicker

I am stuck in weird problem.

I have used `datepicker` like this:

```
<h6>From:</h6>
<input type="text" name="from" data-behaviour='datepicker' data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">

<script type="text/javascript">
     $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
</script>
```

locally datepicker is working fine, but after uploading this to heroku calendar is not opening. I tried the answer as in [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963052/jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work-on-heroku-rails-3-1), after that it started working on IE 8. i am unable to figure out what the problem is. please guide me to right direction. Thanks

Comment: Accept if it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i discovered that i ahve to run 'rake assets:precompile' anyway. i pushed my `public/assets` to git and heroku. i launched firebug and found that the error is related to mixed secure layers. I changed my `jquery` and `jquery-ui` links to `https` previously it was `http` because `heroku` uses `https`. this solved my issue with calendar.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses Modernizr to detect whether the 'date' input type is supported. If it isn't supported, then it fails back to JQueryUI datepicker.

Note: You will need to download JQueryUI and possibly change the paths to the CSS and JS files in your own code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Modernizer Detect 'date' input type</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-1.7-development-only.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            console.log("The 'date' input type is not supported, so using JQueryUI datepicker instead.");
            $("#theDate").datepicker();
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
<body>
        <form>
            <input id="theDate" type="date"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i downloaded and changed all css and js paths. but it even failed on IE too(perviously it was working on IE only). i had to rollback all changes :s

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('input')[0].type != 'date' ) 
    $('input').datepicker();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2AaFk/1/