# rails no route matches after assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am running Rails 3.2.8 application in production mode. 
I have routing problems after i have done "rake assets:precompile".

My log message is :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/corp/assets/application-cf24b2a92e88a02835248f85a9f3c462.css"):
```

This file exists and it is in current location.
My routes are under scope "corp".

My config `"config/application.rb"` have option `"config.assets.enabled = true"`.

My config `"config/environments/production.rb"` have following options:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Application works fine in development mode.
Before that assets:precompile everything was fine.
After few hours of searching of posts i can't find any solution to my problem.
Please help me fix this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In production mode, Rails will not be responsible for serving static assets. Therefore, you are getting this error. This is controlled by this setting in `config/environment/production.rb` in your application:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

You can either set to that `true` or use a real server like Apache or Nginx which will serve the static assets. I suspect Pow may also do it.

**Update**

try this

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = false
```

Comment: It is already set as config.serve_static_assets = true and i am using apache with passenger, but stil have this routing error

Comment: config.assets.compile = true  (doesn't this mean you aren't using the precompiled assets therefore missing on the performance benefits?)

Comment: Down voted because no reference was given to the original author of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets....On second thought, I'm not so sure thats a good reason to downvote but there you go...