# Assets routing error on only 1 action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a strange routing error in my Rails app. I have a controller called `file_ops` and I'm using the REST url philosophy. I can access `index` and `new` just fine, I even have a static route set to an action named `fileScan`. But if I try to go to the `show` action either by typing it in or by link I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets")
```

So far this seems to be the only action that this happens to. I have nothing non-standard in my settings except the static route mentioned above. I've searched around but the other issues people are having seem to be pointing to a file in `/assests` the doesn't exist. Mine seems to be referencing the folder itself.

Comment: some more code or info, plzzzz.

Comment: Have you gone through this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets .. Try setting `config variable` given in above link in your `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: Run `rake routes | grep assets` and include the output from that command in the question; it will help identify the problem.

Comment: @checkit I'm running in development mode the link above seems to only be applicable to production mode. @PrakashMurthy rake returns no results for `assets` but it's still only an error when accessing that one action so far.

Comment: @JasonBurgett you can set for `development mode` also. Thats what I told in my first comment.