# Rails 4 assets not found in production (digest path is OK)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, sprockets, digest

I have problem with assets in production.

I can't load stylesheets, javascripts or even images.

When I try to access to something, it shows me error - not found
But when I try to access with -digest, it's ok.

I have assets precompiled, successfully deployed via capistrano with manifest -> assets_manifest.json

Thanks

Log: stylesheet error (stylesheet loaded with themes_for_rails gem)
When I try access to /assets/default/stylesheets/application-ec9a310f792c60f2f77810cfcd9b903f.css , is everything ok

```
I, [2013-07-17T14:38:45.120183 #31938]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/default/stylesheets/application.css?locale=cs" for 90.181.17.25 at 2013-07-17 14:38:45 +0200
I, [2013-07-17T14:38:45.123007 #31938]  INFO -- : Processing by ThemesForRails::AssetsController#stylesheets as CSS
I, [2013-07-17T14:38:45.123429 #31938]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"locale"=>"cs", "theme"=>"navarsi", "asset"=>"application"}
I, [2013-07-17T14:38:45.124912 #31938]  INFO -- :   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
I, [2013-07-17T14:38:45.125177 #31938]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Image log error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/icons/flags/24/cs.png"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

This is my production environment config

```
Project::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  config.assets.precompile << Ckeditor.assets
  config.assets.precompile << %w(*/fonts/**/*.*)
  config.assets.precompile << %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
  # config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Answer (score 9):

You might be having the same problem as described here: [No route matches [GET] /assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets)

Basically, if you're using rails server to test your app, your precompiled assets wont be served up by default. Rails expects the web server (apache, nginx, etc) to serve them up. You need to make a change to config/environments/production.rb and set serve_static_assets to true.

Comment: But how do I do that? How can I tell Apache to serve files from /assets folder?

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar issue to yours.

Here's my solution for image_tag links: use image_tag asset_path() instead of image_tag '/pic.ext' like this:

```
<%= image_tag asset_path("combat_elephant.png") %>
<%= link_to (image_tag asset_path("puskay_pivka_zahvatyat.png")), "/path" %>
```

Also I'm using nginx for serving static assets, so I have config.serve_static_assets = false and config.assets.compile = true

hope that helps

Comment: Nice! I switched from Rails 3.2.13 to Rails 4, and changing from an <img> tag over to the Rails style made things work.

Comment: First issue was ThemesForRails gem bug. Fixed fork is on my github.

Comment: Rails 4 does work with image_tag in this fashion, so I do not recommend the above pattern.  I fixed this by scrapping my old production.rb file and replacing it with a freshly generated one (i.e. `rails new test`).