# Production-specific routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, rails-routing, assets

Only in my Production environment am I getting this error:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/img/stupid_ghost_asset.png")
```

It's not even appearing in my Staging environment.

This asset does not exist in my repository nor are there any references to this path in any of my CSS, HTML, or JS files.

I cleared the cache on Production, but still nothing. I've even removed and re-precompiled my assets, pushing to both Staging and Production. What else can I do to figure out why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan Bigg does a great job explaining about static_assets on production environment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829852/2620080

This is controlled by this setting in *config/environment/production.rb* in your application:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: I'm hosting on Heroku, so I think Heroku already injects a gem to set that config option to true.