# How to make `thin` webserver print log to STDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thin

Context: To run localhost as SSL, I followed the [instructions at this site](http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2013/07/21/rails_ssl_simple_wa/)

After setting up the SSL cert, to run the local rails server, the site says to:

```
thin start --ssl <some more options>
```

When I do that, I notice that I no longer see the Rails log being printed to STDOUT.

How can I pass the `--ssl` and other options to `thin` ? This does not work:

```
bundle exec rails s thin --ssl

.../rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!': 
    invalid option: --ssl (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

Alternatively, how can I get `thin` to output the Rails log to STDOUT?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7829852/1505348

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i think that you need to tell rails to use `STDOUT` for logging instead of logging to `log/development.log` by putting `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in your `app/config/environments/development.rb`.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work for me because the logging then goes to STDOUT only, instead of to log file as well as STDOUT.

Comment: i don't think there is another way. i did not even know that you have logs going to stdout when you are running rails with `rails server`. i always boot my applications using foreman and tail the logs within there.

Comment: Thanks, foreman solves the problem nicely. I just add a entry for tailing the log file and it is nice!

Answer (score 5):

Well Thin explicitly does not log anything  by default unless you specify it do so by passing options

```
-D or --debug and -V or --trace
```

But having said that this would only track the request / response header of but not rails specific log since your are booting the rails as a rack app perhaps

I guess you need to start rails in ssl mode you can find couple of documentation over [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/) and [here](http://www.railway.at/2013/02/12/using-ssl-in-your-local-rails-environment/)

FYI to use thin as backend adapter in rails all you do is add `gem 'thin'` to the Gemfile 
and start rails it would start rails using thin adapter but you cant pass thin options like you do for when starting thin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `config/environments/development.rb` file is configured to print logs, in case it is not, you can add these lines there.

```rb
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
```