# Rails production datebase error 500 (no such table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment, production

I`m sad, because I get an error 500 when try to start my rails app in *production environment* (in development - works fine)

*logs*

```
...

E, [2013-11-23T13:06:45.285466 #5951] ERROR -- : SQLite3::SQLException: 
   no such table: posts: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"

F, [2013-11-23T13:06:45.299620 #5951] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: posts: 
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"):

...
```

RAILS 4.0.0

ruby 1.9.3p194

I hope this information will be enough. I`m ready to write more...

---

I will be waiting for your help, Friends)

The part of my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5 
  timeout: 5000
```

I`m running this locally

---

I ran *rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production* and it wrote

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:284: 
warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/vitalina/.rvm/bin in PATH, 
mode 040777
db/production.sqlite3 already exists
```

---

I ran

1. sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin
2. rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
3. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

then start server. There isn`t error500 more, but it doesn`t print the information from database (I see an empty page)

and it wrote in logs:

```
...
F, [2013-11-23T14:53:11.909041 #6273] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-
8395b8cd00dfdd4bd6e91eade784fa41.css")
...
```

Comment: Can you copy your database.yml, are you running this locally ?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production` ?

Comment: Did you also migrate your db in production ?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the 500 error, make sure you followed the next steps :

1) `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production`

2) `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

You have now an other problem concerning asset pipeline.
You may find some help here : [No route matches [GET] /assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets)