# Why do assets fail to load in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

**Ruby Version: 2.0.0**

**Rails Version: 4.0.1**

My application development has been going great, until I tried pushing to [ninefold](https://ninefold.com/), where all of my assets broke.

After seeing this I executed a `rails server -e production` and it also looks like everything breaks locally too. What about my production environment could be causing this?

**The log**

```
 Marker - Apr 16, 2014, 7:59:26 PM
I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.178088 #2603]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 19:59:27 -0500
I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.179617 #2603]  INFO -- : Processing by FrontEndController#index as HTML
I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.181418 #2603]  INFO -- :   Rendered front_end/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.182203 #2603]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_frontend_navigation.html.erb (0.2ms)
I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.182498 #2603]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.261664 #2603]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application-1c1eb49916824f465443a709172a580a.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 19:59:27 -0500
F, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.270671 #2603] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-1c1eb49916824f465443a709172a580a.css"):
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.271803 #2603]  INFO -- : Started GET "/stylesheets/frontend.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 19:59:27 -0500
F, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.273875 #2603] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/frontend.css"):
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


I, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.274918 #2603]  INFO -- : Started GET "/javascripts/frontend.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 19:59:27 -0500
F, [2014-04-16T19:59:27.278129 #2603] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/frontend.js"):
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: FYI it’s not common to have Rails serve static assets in production; it’s a task better suited to a “traditional” web server like Nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting config.serve_static_assets = false in config/environments/production.rb ?(see [No route matches [GET] /assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets))