# No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/frontend.css"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

**Ruby Version: 2.0.0**

**Rails Version: 4.0.1**

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Why do assets fail to load in production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122831/why-do-assets-fail-to-load-in-production-mode). This was mostly fixed by setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in **production.rb**.

However, now I still have one stylesheet and one javascript file that aren't being pulled in. which (coincidentally) should be pulling in it's own set of dependencies.

In my application.html.erb file I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"  %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "frontend", media: "all" %>
```

However, that seems to be parsing to two *very* different things. Here is the output:

```
<link href="/assets/application-1c1eb49916824f465443a709172a580a.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/frontend.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in case it makes a difference, here is what frontend.css actually looks like:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./frontend
 *= require front_end
 */
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `config/application.rb`, add `frontend.css` to `config.assets.precompile`:

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( frontend.css )
```

Don't forget to do this if you create other CSS and JavaScript manifest files.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I remember going through all of this when deploying my first production app. Good luck. :)

Comment: Ok. I added the assets' entries in `config.assets.precompile` in `config/application.rb` just as sugested. i.e using `config.assets.precompile += %w( whateverasset|css|js )`

This worked

Comment: It should be noted that the location of this configuration has moved to `config/initializers/assets.rb` in newer versions of Rails.