# Precompiled assets Images from gems not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app can't find precompiled images from gems in production.  All other assets are working as is all assets in development.  I get the following error when running in production mode;

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/dataTables/sort_asc.png"):
```

The assets seem to precompiled properly, images from app/assets/images show up.

Can someone shed some light on the problem?

Comment: could you show us how you are calling this `.png` in the view?

Comment: I got it working by following the answer by albert.qing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompiling assets worked for me.

**remove public/assets**

> 1.rake assets:clobber RAILS_ENV=production

**assets compile**

> 2.rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
>
> 3.restart server,eg(nginx)

credit to albert.qing's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829480/no-route-matches-get-assets)

I might add that I am using docker so I added this step towards the end of my docker file

/Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.3-slim
.
.
.
# Precompile Rails assets
RUN bundle exec rake assets:clobber RAILS_ENV=production
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
.
.
.
```