# Rails 3 Doesn't Look In Public Folder For Assets On Show Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, get, paperclip

In my show views whenever I try and display an image using the image_tag builder rails doesn't look for images in the public folder inside of my show views...

For instance:

```
<%= image_tag "thumbnails/fish.jpg" %>
```

Will produce this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/thumbnails/fish.jpg"):
```

I'm using the paperclip Gem for my upload model and **I'm saving uploads to a different folder than the public folder** for security reasons, and yes, this show view does occur within the Upload controller...

In my Upload model I use this line to save uploads to a non-public folder:

```
has_attached_file :upload,  :path => ":rails_root/:class/:id/:basename.:extension",
                            :url => ":rails_root/:class  /:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Rake routes:

```
upload GET    /uploads/:id(.:format)                                                                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"uploads"}
       PUT    /uploads/:id(.:format)                                                                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"uploads"}
       DELETE /uploads/:id(.:format)                                                                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"uploads"}
              /download/:id(.:format)                                                                {:controller=>"uploads", :action=>"download"}
```

**Edit**
Note: If I explicitly make an img tag and point the src to my image it works fine on my show views so I don't think it's a permission issue.

Comment: what is the exact path to your images?

Comment: rails_app/public/images/thumbnails/image.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was fairly simple, and I can't believe Rails is being this picky but I needed to include a forward slash at the beginning of the path as so:

```
"thumbnails/fish.jpg"
```

becomes

```
"/thumbnails/fish.jpg"
```

I'm still curious as to why this is only a problem on non-index views...

Comment: By non-index views, did you mean those that are not `http://example.com/` , but `http://example.com/someview` or `http://example.com/anotherview` ?  If yes, then the difference is:  having a leading slash defines an absolute path from your index view; without the leading slash, it's a relative path, meaning you're accessing `/someview/thumbnails/fish.jpg`, which is the wrong path.

Comment: I meant literally the index route. Evidently there's a difference between `GET /model ` and `GET /model/id` when serving assets. Either that or there's a problem with my routes.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change this line to true:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

in the environment/*.rb file (e.g. development.rb).

Or I have seen where this is a permissions issue on the directory in question so a CHMOD 777 on the directory may resolve it/point you in the right direction.

Here is an [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106820/rails-3-1-actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-assets-rails) on a similar issue

Comment: I don't actually have that line in any of my enviroment.rbs - I'm using Rails 3.1.3

Comment: It's no there because it defaults to false already, but you can add it, setting it to true