# Rails Paperclip precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, precompile

I modified my Paperclip-using model like this:

```
class UsersPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :user_id, :users_picture_id, :photo
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :photo,
   :url => "users_pictures/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension",
   :path => ":rails_root/users_pictures/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"

before_create :rename_file_name

def rename_file_name
  extension = File.extname(photo_file_name).downcase
  filename = File.basename(photo_file_name).downcase
  timestamp = Time.now.to_i
  name = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{filename}")
  self.photo.instance_write(:file_name, "#{name}_#{timestamp}#{extension}")
end
end
```

Before I inserted the before_create method, everything was fine.
But now my log says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (users_pictures/photos/88/8b7474622cf5bbc140ed7defe1ae76a8_1351088476.jpeg isn't precompiled):
8: <p>
9:   <b>Users picture file:</b>
10:  <% if @users_picture.photo.exists? then %>
11:             <%= image_tag @users_picture.photo.url %>
12:         <% end %>
13: </p>
14: 
app/views/users_pictures/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_pictures_show_html_erb__597237708__324410398'
app/controllers/users_pictures_controller.rb:18:in `show'
```

I was searching for solutions but there was always remembered to use "image_tag". But I am currently using it ?
The index works just fine of course, but the show method does not :/
What can I change ?
Edit: When I remove the image_tag, I get:
users_pictures/photos/88/8b7474622cf5bbc140ed7defe1ae76a8_1351088476.jpeg

And this is also the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the image path with /

```
<%= image_tag "/" + @users_picture.photo.url %>
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318133/418819